# Dell PE 1950 no network connectivity while cable/connection seem good (windows 2008 std)

Tags: networking, dell-poweredge

The title pretty much says it: The box seems to be connected to the network, but from within the OS (Windows 2008 Standard) there's no connectivity. A ping to the gateway returns a reply from local interface "Destination Unreachable". I can't see any faults hardware-wise, both in BIOS and inside Windows. Disabling/Enabling NIC cycles up to the point where windows tries to "identify" network. Lights on the switch indicate a 1Gb connection, so I decided not to re-wire for now to rule out bad cable.

Adapter has a hardcoded IP. If I switch to DHCP, the query times out and NIC is configured with auto-configuration address.

So it feels as if connection is there (both windows and switch detect cable connected), but at the same time there's no connectivity.

I tried enabling and disabling Windows Firewall to no avail.

Completely powered down Windows/server, unplugged power cables (dual PSU), looked to re-seat NIC (it's a dual), but they seem to be on the main board.

If it matters, it's an Active Directory domain controller.

I made no changes since it was working fine - just one day it stopped being visible to machines on the domain - logging onto the console revealed the above.

Not sure how to even start troubleshooting. Is there a way to test before Windows boots - to eliminate Windows/Drivers/Firewall?

Other troubleshooting suggestions?

**ADDITION**

Switching to the other NIC port (it's a dual port NIC on the main board) solves the connectivity issue, so it looks like a problem with the first port.

I also see the following event in the server's System Event Log, from when I opened the rack (but the connectivity issue had been there for hours already):

`A bus fatal error was detected on a component at bus 0 device 3 function 0.`

followed by

`An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.`

Comment: 1. Change the cable. 2. Change the switch port. 3. Make sure that the NIC and switch port are either hard-coded to the same speed and duplex settings or that they're both configured for Auto-negotiation.

Comment: I assume that this PowerEdge came with a DRAC card with its own dedicated NIC. Are you sure that you are **not** using that NIC but a NIC which is available to the OS?

Comment: @Hennes, it's not that - the server had been working for a year and no changes were made when it disappeared from the network.

Comment: don't think there is much to troubleshoot if " bus 0 device 3 function 0" is related to the 1st nic, basically this is saying the device is fried.

Comment: @tonyroth, thanks for commenting. Could you comment why I am seeing good connection, though? - I.e. Windows thinks cable is connected, the switch, too. I posted this particular question separately here: http://serverfault.com/questions/516242/arp-a-refreshes-its-cache-but-windows-has-no-connection

Comment: there are many layers to a nic card going even lower then the osi model but not discussed since at these layers there are probably no standards, I'd suspect that part just prior to level 1 is going nuts but level 1 is able to apply the correct line signaling.

Comment: So would that be a logic board on the NIC? The fact that the other port (it's a dual port NIC) works probably means that there are two logial circuits?? (And they're actually on the main board, not on a separate PCI-e card).

Comment: yes its silicon at this point.

Comment: damn implants!!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions.....(1) look at your Windows firewall setting, (2) try a different port on the ethernet card maybe the port has a problem, (3) try a different ethernet card, it might be defective, (4) Try using a different OS (kidding ...), (5) power cycle the server, (7) check the switch connection by moving to a different switch port, (8) verify that the switch port and the windows port are autonegotiating correctly (same speed, and same duplex).

That would be a start.

Comment: (1) As I say in my post, I tried disabling windows firewall. (2) and (3): that's really not what I am looking for: my goal is to definitively explain "this" port - the one with the problem. Tried (5) and (7), too. I believe (8) can also be ruled out. What was (6)? :-)