# `arp -a` refreshes its cache, but windows has no connection

Tags: networking, dell-poweredge

I've got a DELL PE 1950 running Windows 2008 R2 Std. Few days ago I lost connectivity to the server (in a rack)

Troubleshooting at the console and the switch reveals seemingly good connection, but with no connectivity to any windows function (from DHCP, to PING, to server traffic).

I already have another SF question going about troubleshooting the entire issue, but I wanted to ask a very specific question: if the switch and Windows see "cable connected", connection seems to have been negotiated (1 Gb full duplex), what are possible reasons for NIC failure?

In other words, it looks like the physical media and the lower layers of the network stack seem to be operational - is there a way to confirm that and isolate the faulty "layer"/component?

For example `arp-a` displays cached MAC addresses of machines that are currently on the network. Deleting that cache with `arp -d` empties it, but enabling/disabling the interface seems to trigger a rebuild.

The switch shows "green" lights for that connection.

Testing the switch port and cable show that they're fine.

Am I right to think that some of the layers are working?

Comment: Are there any vlans involved?

Comment: Not that I am aware; not intentionally. Where do I check?